# finding the minimum slope of a tangent line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a tangent line that touches the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{18-2x}}$ at $x=a$, $(0\le a\le 7)$.

Need to find the value of $x=a$ when the slope of the tangent line will be minimum.

I found that there are no $x$ such that $f(x)'=0$ so i need to check the endpoints, but where do i check them? in $f(x)$ or $f'(x)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are minimizing the slope of the tangent line, you should be looking at where the derivative of the equation of the slope of the tangent line is zero. The slope of the tangent line is given by $f'(x)$, so you should be finding where the derivitive of *that* is equal to zero. I.e. where does $f''(x)$ = 0?

Comment: @mapierce271 - thanks but even then i found that x=9 is a solution for $f''(x)=0$ and it's not in the given range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{18-2x}}$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(18-2x)^{3/2}}$.  Now, we need to examine the second derivative to see if this function is monotonic on $[0,7].$  We have
$$f''(x)=\frac{3}{(18-2x)^{5/2}}$$ which means $f(x)$ is monotonic for all $x$ in the domain since $f''(x)$ is never equal to $0$.  Therefore, it is sufficient to check only the endpoints and plug them into $f'(x)$.  Plugging $x=0$ into $f'(x)$ we have
$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{18^{3/2}}\approx .0131$$
and plugging $x=7$ into $f'(x)$ we have
$$f'(7)=\frac{1}{4^{3/2}}\approx .125.$$
Since $f'(0)<f'(7)$ then we can conclude $f(x)$ has minimum slope of tangent line when $x=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the formula for the $f'(x)$, we have $f'(x)=(18-2x)^{-3/2}$.   Note that in our domain of $[0,7]$,  as x increases,  $18-2x$  decreases,  then raising that to a negative power makes it increase,  hence $f'(x)$  is an increasing function on $[0,7]$  Thus, it will be minimized at the beginning of the domain,  at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

So you know that $f'(x)$ is the slope. Now what you want to do is minimise the slope. This is where you should think: minimise means taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero, then figuring out which zeros of the derivative are minima. So you want to find $f''(X)$ and set it equal to zero, and then determining its minimum from that.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't answering my question because even then i found that $f''(9)=0$ but $x=a=9$ is not in the given range.

Comment: @diva So it has no zeros in the given range? Then you need to check the endpoints of $f'(x)$. The smallest of them will be the minimum.

Comment: ok so i need to put $x=0,7$ is $f'(x)$. thanks!